# Plot latencies from input csv

Tags: r, plot

I have preprocessed data in which I "distille" some information from many pcap files, resulting in something like this:

```
device, command type, latency, device id
Nokia 3310,          turn on,  22, 1
Nokia 3310,          turn off, 12, 1
Nokia 3310,          turn on,  20, 2
Nokia 3310,          turn off, 14, 2
Nokia 3310,          turn on,  21, 3
Nokia 3310,          turn off, 19, 3
Nokia 3310,          turn on,   2, 4
Nokia 3310,          send sms, 12, 4
candle,              turn on,   5, 1
candle,              turn off,  1, 1
Nuclear power plant, turn on,  64, 1
Nuclear power plant, turn off, 32, 1
Car,                 turn on,   7, 1
Car,                 turn off,  2, 1
Car,                 fuel,     42, 1
```

I would like to do box plot (I mean something like this https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/boxplot1.jpg ), where I will see:

- X-axis, device type (device column)
- Y-axis, latency
- "turn on" latency should be with one color"
- "turn off" latency should be with one color"
- other command types should not be visualized
- note, that not all devices does have all operations and some have more than one observations (i.e. Nokia 3310 have more "turn on" samples...

I think that I have more tasks/problems. I.e. I would perhaps need to categorize data first.

My current approach is this:

```
> library(readr)
> stack <- read_csv("stack.csv")

── Column specification ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
cols(
  device = col_character(),
  `command type` = col_character(),
  latency = col_double(),
  `device id` = col_double()
)

> plot(stack$device, stack$latency)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

PS: I have little to no knowledge about R-project (just some more than 10 years old things from other job).

Comment: Maybe you want a histogram... Calculate frequencies first using `aggregate(latency ~ device, FUN = mean, data = stack)`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, your command works and prints mean latencies for each devices for all operations. I need to restrict input only to two particular operations and put it into single graph. I have tried `hist(stack$latency[startsWith(stack$device, 'Nokia 3310')])` but this way, I will need two (two operations) histogram charts per single device and I have about 10 of devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with `boxplot`?

You may use a subset of `stack` by filtering for `"turn"` using `grep`.

```
stack <- read.csv("test2.csv", strip.white=TRUE)
boxplot(latency ~ device, stack[grep("^turn", stack$command.type), ],
        main="This could be your title", col="#fac194")
```

[image]

#### Edit

Actually, it might be wise to use the `subset=` feature of `boxplot`. As you found out by yourself we may use `add=TRUE` to overplot mutliple plots. For the boxes to be better distinguishable we may play around with the `at=` argument and use custom `axes`:

```
boxplot(latency ~ device, stack, subset=command.type == "turn on", 
        xlim=c(0.5, 4.5), boxwex=0.25, main="This could be your title", 
        col="#fac194", at=1:4 - 0.2, xaxt="n", border="#F48024")
boxplot(latency ~ device, stack, subset=command.type == "turn off", 
        boxwex=0.25, col="#ff9d9d", add=T, 
        at=1:4 + 0.2, xaxt="n", border="red")
axis(1, 1:4, labels=sort(unique(stack$device)))
legend("topleft", c("turn on", "turn off"), pt.bg=c("#fac194", "#ff9d9d"), 
       col=c("#F48024", "red"), pch=22)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
stack <- structure(list(device = c("Nokia 3310", "Nokia 3310", "Nokia 3310", 
"Nokia 3310", "Nokia 3310", "Nokia 3310", "Nokia 3310", "Nokia 3310", 
"candle", "candle", "Nuclear power plant", "Nuclear power plant", 
"Car", "Car", "Car"), command.type = c("turn on", "turn off", 
"turn on", "turn off", "turn on", "turn off", "turn on", "send sms", 
"turn on", "turn off", "turn on", "turn off", "turn on", "turn off", 
"fuel"), latency = c(22L, 12L, 20L, 14L, 21L, 19L, 2L, 12L, 5L, 
1L, 64L, 32L, 7L, 2L, 42L), device.id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: Ehm, I have tried only `plot(...)` command. This seems that generates same results as I expect. To accept answer, I just need to filter lines only with "turn on" command and also "turn off" and make them appear in same chart... Additionally, I ave some data "N/A", i.e. no value for latency. I would like just ignore (filter out) them.

Comment: @Lubo Just to understand it right, that would omit the `fuel` rows? Or do you need additional grouping?

Comment: I think that single grouping would be enough (by device, if I omit that given single command will be counted only) and I need to filter out "sms send" and "fuel" commands. I think that filtering would be done against command == "turn on" for single chart and than add to same chart command == "turn off". It is so?

Comment: @Lubo See edit, is that what you want? Else try with expanding the formula to `latency ~ device + command.type`.

Comment: There is perhaps one comma (or missing parameter to filtering) in your edit. When I remove given comma, this jumps on me: `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'latency' not found`. PS: It seems basically that it is what I need. Sidenote, is it ok to use `startsWith` instead of grep?

Comment: @Lubo Ah yes sorry, use `strip.white=TRUE` in `read.csv`, there was a bunch of white space in `"            turn on/off"`! The `^`  accounts to be start of string, however, sure, you could also use `startsWith(stack$command.type, "turn")`.

Comment: @jay.st Thanks, my nearly final solution would be: `boxplot(latency ~ device, stack[grep("^turn on", stack$command.type), ], main="This could be your title", col="#fac194")` and `boxplot(latency ~ device, stack[grep("^turn off", stack$command.type), ], main="This could be your title", col="red", add=TRUE)`

Comment: @Lubo I like your attempt and enhanced it a little.

Comment: @Lubo You could try `panel.bpplot` of the [`Hmisc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package. I've never used it before, though, because 1.5*IQR should be standard.

Comment: I believe, that labels on x axis is in wrong order. What about to use `levels` method, instead of `unique`? Does it solve this problem? PS: I have looked at nuclear power plants data (just one 32 and one 64 observation).

Comment: @Lubo Oh yes, I'm sorry didn't notice. The boxes are `sorted` alphabetically, so we do with the labels. See edit.